# receiving null value upon requesting getAttribute() from JSP file

Tags: json, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I have a json file containing some data like so:

poll.json

```
{
    "poll": {
        "title": "About your preferences",
        "questions": [
            "Which color do you like best?",
            "What is your lucky number?",
            "Why?"
        ]
    }
}
```

In my servlet I read the json file and process the data and store the "title" item from the json table into titleString. after that (here where the trouble starts) I replace the "oldTitle" from my jsp file with "titleString".

PollServlet.java

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
        response.setContentType("text/json");
        /* create bufferedReader to read the file.json */
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(
                getClass().getResourceAsStream("poll/poll.json"))); 
        JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(br);
        br.close();
        /* create json object and store it into titleString */
        JsonObject jsonObject = reader.readObject();
        String titleString = jsonObject
                .getJsonArray("poll").getJsonObject(0).toString();
         /* replace the item with atribute "oldTitle" to titleString*/
         request.setAttribute("oldTitle",titleString);
         getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(
         "/poll.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }
```

and here is the poll.jsp file where I set the attribute

```
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form>
            <a><% out.print(request.getAttribute("oldTitle"));%></a><br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
            <br>

            What is your lucky number? <br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" value="">
            <br>
            Why? <br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" value="">
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Done">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is when I run my project all I get is "null" instead of the titleString in the  tag inside the  what causes the problem? thanks

Comment: "poll" not json array. try like this jsonObject.getJsonObject("poll").getJsonString("title").toString();

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt thanks but I don't think the problem is from this. I changed it and still no change

Comment: Is servlet is being invoked correctly? and what's inside processRequest(request, response) method?

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt I posted the code as is. should there be something in them.